# Calculate age using lubridate in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I am a bit confused of the result from the R package `lubridate_1.2.0`:

```
> as.period(difftime(as.Date('2013-03-01'),as.Date('1960-03-01')))
estimate only: convert difftimes to intervals for accuracy
[1] "52y 0m 365d 0H 0M 0S"
```

Should the answer be `53y`, rather than `52y and 365d`?

#### update 01

I have found the fix of it

```
> as.period(new_interval(as.Date('1960-03-01'),as.Date('2013-03-01')))
[1] "53y 0m 0d 0H 0M 0S"
```

But what is the difference between the two functions?

Comment: Try taking a look at the source code; they're both very readable.

Comment: Please check ?as.period   There is explanation.